# Simple non clickable text in semantic-ui dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui and I want to show some info text in `dropdown`. But it act as a link even it's a `<div class="header item">`

[image]

Here profile, settings and logout are link and rest are text(non-clickable)

sample mockup I tried with.

`<div class="ui dropdown item">
      <i class="icon dropdown"></i>
        <div class="menu hidden">
            <div class="header item">Narottam Guattom</div>
            <a href="#" class="item">Action one</a>
            <a href="#" class="item">Action one</a>
            <a href="#" class="item">Action one</a>
        </div>
    </div>`

Semantic-ui treat that `div` as a link and dropdown get closed on click.
**Is there better way to implement this in semantic-ui Or how can I prevent click event.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should customize items selector. Try to use next code

```
$.fn.dropdown.settings.selector.item = '.menu > .item:not(.header)'; // change selector for all dropdowns
```

Also you can specify item selector locally. Read more about [dropdown DOM settings](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings) to configure it properly

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".header " ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
........//Custom code 
});
```

Comment: not worked because they use `js` to toggle dropdown. It's called by their toggle function also execute.